# Convert contract creation code to contract source code

Tags: web3js, contract-deployment, bytecode

I already get the bytecode of a contract from web3 through this method: web3.eth.getCode(address), but I am having trouble decoding this code to a human readable form. How do I do it?

Take the OMG Token contract code as an example: https://etherscan.io/address/0xd26114cd6EE289AccF82350c8d8487fedB8A0C07#code

I was trying to convert the contract creation code in the bottom:

> 6003805460a060020a61ffff0219169055600060045560a0604052600860608190527f4f4d47546f6b656e000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000608090815261005491600591906100c1565b506040805180820190915260038082527f4f4d4700000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006020909201918252610099916006916100c1565b5060126007555b60038054600160a060020a03191633600160a060020a03161790555b610161565b828054600181.............................................

to a human readable contract source code on the top.

Answer (score 1):

There are no good proven solutions, however, you can try using a decompiler, see https://www.pnfsoftware.com/blog/ethereum-smart-contract-decompiler/.

Of course this isn't well tested, so I can't guarantee this will work.